# Polymer paper-input with google places autocomplete

Tags: polymer, google-places-api

Is it possible to connect the input of the paper-input component with the [Google Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) library?  I'm trying to get the places dropdown effect combined with the [paper-input behavior](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/demo.html)

Comment: Use paper input decorator then bind the autocomplete to the nested input field. Will write a complete answer later. Sorry, just seeing this.

Comment: A nice implementation can be found here for multiline addresses: https://github.com/kunalkundaje/address-autocomplete

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code for getting google places Autocomplete with Polymer paper input

First you need to import google maps web components 
you can download google-maps element from https://googlewebcomponents.github.io/

```
<link rel="import" href="components/google-maps/google-maps.html">
```

Then you can use the following code. Call initialize function at page onload. When you type any address in the input the autocomplete will show up and when you choose any item from the autocomplete then callback will be initiated.

```
<paper-input id="search"></paper-input>
<script>
var autocomplete;
function initialize()
{
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('search')), {types:['geocode']});
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', callBack);
}
function callback()
{
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  //console.log(place.geometry.location.lat());
}
</script>
```

You can find out more about Google places autocomplete from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

Someone has already written the element [here](https://github.com/x-element/input-location/blob/master/input-location.html), just replace input with paper-input & add import.

Also pay attention, "libraries" attribute must me exactly the same on every google maps element.

Comment: Same here:https://github.com/kunalkundaje/address-autocomplete - depends on what kind of input you are looking for